# Unity - Help wanted with meshes using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a rather difficult to explain question I'd like to put out in an off-chance that there are unity masters out there would be able to assist. I'm trying to get the positions of each point within a mesh; when you apply the wire-frame function, you can see the triangles that make the mesh, but I don't know how to extract the positions of each triangle. I'm trying to achieve this by writing a c# script.

If there is anyone who can help, I will be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just retrieve the [MeshFilter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MeshFilter.html) component that contains the [Mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) data:

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
...
```